# Postman form-data works (WebAPI can parse 1) but raw data does not (WebAPI receives 0, instead of initial 1) in .NET 6.0 WebAPI controller GET request

Tags: c#, request, get, postman, webapi

I am using Postman to test my .NET 6.0 WebAPI.

When I try to process a form-data request, the WebAPI gets the original value of "parameter"
[image]

When I try to process a raw data request, the WebAPI gets the default value of "parameter"

[image]

This is the code of my .NET 6.0 controller:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class SiteInfoController : Controller

{
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Test")]
    public IActionResult Test(int parameter)
    {
        return Ok($"response: {parameter}");
    }
}
```

I added in Headers

```
Content-Type application/json
Accept application/json
```

but it didn't help me
Please help me to find the reason why form-data works (WebAPI can parse 1) but raw data does not (WebAPI receives 0, instead of initial 1) in .NET 6.0 WebAPI controller GET request.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to read an object from the body of a request. You must define said object and tell the framework where to read it from. And `HttpGet` can't have a body. You must use `HttpPost` or any other verb that can handle it:

```cs
[Route("[controller]")]
public class SiteInfoController : Controller
{

    private sealed class MyParameter
    {
        public int Parameter { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Test")]
    public IActionResult Test([FromBody] MyParameter parameter)
    {
        return Ok($"response: {parameter.Parameter}");
    }
}
```

Make sure you change your PostMan script to use `Post` and not `Get`.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation, Andy. It all makes sense to me now.